# JavaScript: can I somehow strong type function parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie with JavaScript and I feel the unresistible need to strong type my functions parameters for a couple of tools I am coding:

1. That would give me autocompletion within those functions
2. Debugging/function access gets more consistent

After some googling, I guess this isn't directly possible. However, are there common tools to emulate this rather simply?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Nope, at least not in the sense that would allow you to use any of the points that you mentioned.

Comment: The language is just not like that. As with any other new language you learn, it's very important to resist the temptation to import idioms from other languages you're already familiar with.  Let JavaScript be JavaScript and you'll get along with it just fine.

Comment: When it is necessary to check the type of a variable in javascript, the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function can be used to determine a variable's type. However, it returns 'object' for arrays and null. To check if a variable is an array use `Array.isArray` and for null use `var === null`. This can also be combined with other checks. For example, to check if a variable is an integer use: `typeof(var) === 'number' && Math.floor(var) === var`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't and even if there is a way you shouldn't. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. For auto completion you can however use [JSDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) style documentation tags that give some type pointers:

```
var Person = {
    /**
     * Say hi
     * @param {String} name The name to say hi to
     * @return {String}
     */
    sayHi : function(name)
    {
        return 'Hi ' + name;
    }
}
```

If they are being used depends entirely on your IDE though.

Comment: Javascript 2, due to be finalized by the end of 2013, will add optional strong typing.

Comment: a) I still think that is a bad idea and b) this won't make it into production till maybe three years from now.

Comment: Strong typing allows developers to more quickly catch errors that WILL otherwise happen at runtime. Why do you think that's a bad idea?

Comment: Because JavaScript isn't a strongly typed language. And you always trade safety vs. flexibility and ease of use. If you want (optional) static typing, there are alternatives like TypeScript and Dart.

Comment: What is "autocompletion" ?

Answer (score 13):

People writing "you shouldn't use it" are wrong. In the next Java Script 2.x specification there is a plan to add strong typed variables.

Meanwhile you may use very simple solution to emulate strong types:

```
var = Object.create( String );
```

After that autocompleting in a lot of IDE (including IntelliJ IDEA) will work great and you have declared and initialized an object of specified type.

Read more on [my blog](http://floatoverflow.blogspot.com/2014/02/emulation-of-strong-types-in-javascript.html).

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at Typescript? Its an open source project by Microsoft that allows you to develop using strong typing and then compiles the code into Javascript. I know is Microsoft but take a look before you dismiss it.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/

---

Edit 2017

There are now two big players on this scene, Typescript (as suggested above) has been battle proven and is now used extensively by Angular 2. If structure and fairly rigid typing if what you are looking for, that is your best bet.

Another option is Flow (https://flow.org/) it was developed by Facebook and is used by them heavily in React. Flow allows you to only specify which files you want to type check and is a lower barrier to entry IMO.

It is worth saying that adding type checking adds a fair amount of complexity to your build process - it requires you to have a build process!

Comment: Yes, Daff suggested it in his comment

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)?

Certain IDEs (like Jetbrains' products) try to understand JSDoc and help out, but sometimes their annotation parser conflicts with Google Closure's. However, even with Closure you're not gonna get perfect strong typing.

Also, it might be overkill, but look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript recognizes the following types of values:

**Numbers**: such as 42 or 3.14159

**Logical (Boolean)**: values either true or false

**Strings**: such as "Howdy!"

**null**: a special keyword denoting a null value; null is also a primitive value. Because JavaScript is case-sensitive, null is not the same as Null, NULL, or any other variant

**undefined**: a top-level property whose value is undefined; undefined is also a primitive value.

***There is no explicit distinction between integer and real-valued numbers*** [...]

***JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. That means you do not have to specify the data type of a variable when you declare it, and data types are converted automatically as needed during script execution***

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals

So, no, you can't use strong type in JavaScript

Comment: this is not helping

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a system that **handles the type checks automatically**, using a wrapper in your function.

> With this approach, you can build a complete `declarative type check system` that will manage for you the type checks .
>   If you are interested in taking a more in depth look at this concept, check the [Functyped library](https://github.com/colxi/functyped)

The following implementation illustrates the main idea, in a simplistic, but **operative way** :

```js
/*
 * checkType() : Test the type of the value. If succeds return true, 
 * if fails, throw an Error
 */
function checkType(value,type, i){
  // perform the appropiate test to the passed 
  // value according to the provided type
  switch(type){
    case Boolean : 
      if(typeof value === 'boolean') return true;
      break;
    case String : 
      if(typeof value === 'string') return true;
      break;
    case Number : 
      if(typeof value === 'number') return true;
      break;
    default :
      throw new Error(`TypeError : Unknown type provided in argument ${i+1}`);
  }
  // test didn't succeed , throw error
  throw new Error(`TypeError : Expecting a ${type.name} in argument ${i+1}`);
}


/*
 * typedFunction() : Constructor that returns a wrapper
 * to handle each function call, performing automatic 
 * arguments type checking
 */
function typedFunction( parameterTypes, func ){
  // types definitions and function parameters 
  // count must match
  if(parameterTypes.length !== func.length) throw new Error(`Function has ${func.length} arguments, but type definition has ${parameterTypes.length}`);
  // return the wrapper...
  return function(...args){
    // provided arguments count must match types
    // definitions count
    if(parameterTypes.length !== args.length) throw new Error(`Function expects ${func.length} arguments, instead ${args.length} found.`);
    // iterate each argument value, and perform a
    // type check against it, using the type definitions
    // provided in the construction stage
    for(let i=0; i<args.length;i++) checkType( args[i], parameterTypes[i] , i)
    // if no error has been thrown, type check succeed
    // execute function!
    return func(...args);
  }
}

// Play time! 
// Declare a function that expects 2 Numbers
let myFunc = typedFunction( [ Number, Number ],  (a,b)=>{
  return a+b;
});

// call the function, with an invalid second argument
myFunc(123, '456')
// ERROR! Uncaught Error: TypeError : Expecting a Number in argument 2
```

Answer (score 0):

no you can't; javascript is a weakly typed language. This means that JavaScript will figure out what type of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into compiling your work using "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" in Google Closure Compiler which will do type checking of your arguments or variables.

[Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler: Type Expressions](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#type-expressions)

**Example data types:** boolean, Window, goog.ui.Menu, string, number

Here's an example of declaring a variable and its data type. If you try to set the variable into another data type, it will give you an error or warning message after compiling.

```
/**
 * The message hex ID.
 * @type {string}
 */
var hexId = hexId;
```

Here is an example of a class declaration with possible parameter types:

```
/**
 * Some class, initialized with an optional value.
 * @param {Object=} opt_value Some value (optional).
 * @constructor
 */
function MyClass(opt_value) {
  /**
   * Some value.
   * @type {Object|undefined}
   */
  this.myValue = opt_value;
}
```

Using the "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS," makes you write JavaScript a little more properly since it also gives some link