# Is there any way to make JS strongly typed?

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion, coercion, type-coercion

JavaScript is a weakly dynamically typed language. I don't mind the dynamic typing, but the weak typing means lots of frustration at unexpected type coercion when I least expect it. Lots of articles online claim to solve this issue but they all confuse weak typing with dynamic typing, and propose solutions such as TypeScript. I would like something more similar to Python's type behaviours - dynamically typed variables but no implicit type coercion. Is there a language or library that does this?

Comment: Maybe one day: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-type-annotations

Answer (score 8):

No it isn't, and it is the reason why [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) was built.
Your question is also kind of a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789752/javascript-can-i-somehow-strong-type-function-parameters). Have a look, you may find some answers ;)

That said, you could use a good IDE, even [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) try to help with their [Javscript type checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking), worth have a look.

Here a small implementation example

```
//@ts-check

export class Dog {
  /**
  * @param {string} name
  * @param {number} age
  */
  constructor(name, age) {
    super()
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }

  speak () {
    console.log(`${this.name}: No! No more talk!`)
  }
}

new Dog(7, 'Wez').speak() // <-- You should get an error here, it should be Dog('wez', 7)
```

**Edit**
If you really wants to have a strong type language for the web, you may :

- Use [webassembly](https://webassembly.org/) to bring your python code into the browser -> https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-python
- Give a look at the [typescene framework](https://typescene.dev/) which claim to be *a robust Web app framework made with TypeScript: strongly typed*, but I never tested it to be honest.

Comment: Again, that's static typing, not strong typing. I meant something like Python.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 For the title of your question "Is there any way to make JS strongly typed?" response is no, as written & explained, for the "Is there a language or library that does this?" I've updated my response, see the `edit`. Hope it helps